# How to create a facebook login like yahoo:

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

If you click here:

http://shine.yahoo.com/parenting/time-magazines-breastfeeding-cover-moms-react-185700989.html

and then click on "**Login with Facebook**", then a popup will be opened. In this popup you can do the facebook login but it is different from the classic facebook login:

Infact the **publish action permission** appears in this popup instead in the classic facebook login the publish action permission appears in the next step.

How can I create a facebook login like yahoo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the iframe in the popup that is rendered, everything in the dialog is being served from Facebook. This must be the result of some type of special partnership Yahoo has with Facebook. This probably got started when Yahoo offered to buy Facebook in 2006.

My guess is to get this kind of setup, you need to know someone in bizdev at Facebook and be able to drive a substantial amount of traffic to their site.

Answer (score 0):

Both Facebook and yahoo use openID for authentication and Outh for authoriazation.in facebook use you need to us there api libraries for authorization read the documentation [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#feed)you should have some javascript  or a server side scripting language knowledege.for yahoo the same still applies.Yahoo uses oauth 2.0 for authorization.when the yahoo users cliks the sign-in button he/she is redirected to yahoo using the outh system if he /she allows your application he/she is then redirected to your site using the url you specified in the creating apps with yahoo.you an read the documentaion here>/a>
if you need to create a dialog like facebook style then you need to have some css javascript or jquery knowledge,however there is a simple plugin the lightbox or fancybox plugin where you can create an iframe or div tag whichwillhold the contents of the dialog.